# how to fix ubuntu overheating

Tags: intel-graphics, cpu, overheating

I'm new to Ubuntu but not to Linux and this is the first time overheating has been an issue for me. I'm using the latest version with all the updates installed and my computer has a Intel Core i5-3317U with the  integrated hd 4000  drivers installed from Intel's graphics installer but the computer still runs with temperatures in the 60 degree range making it quite unusable. The problem does not exist on OpenSuse, or windows 8. Any way to fix this heating issue?
\
Thanks.

Comment: Why is 60 degree C making it unusable? Can you show the output of `sensors` if it lists temperatures? (maybe it's not configured)

Answer (score 3):

I noticed such issues in the past which is to be frankly honest not related to the OS itself but the support of the hardware to that OS

for example I had earlier an unsupported graphics card and after playing around with the configurations made the CPU doesn't sleep on idle thus making the fan spins all the time yet doesn't cool down especially when working in warm environment.

Being a thinkpad user didn't hurt much, but still its not a solution to have external pad that include fans to cool down your PC.

My recommendation is having full list of your hardware and comparing the support of each vendor and its drivers then if the problem still exists.

Last experience also if your CPU configured to max out always and do not work on demand this could be a problem of overheating, look at [Jupiter or similar apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681) that could help you achieve that

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an Ubuntu problem?  What I do with my PC's is limit the useage in the BIOS program.  During boot somewhere around the post page, you have to hit a particular key, such as delete to enter the BIOS program.  When in the BIOS program you have many choices, one is usually to limit the CPU run time useage.  I run my CPU's @ about 79%.  Find a useage that gets your CPU down to an acceptable temperature.